# Lambda listening to s3 events should trigger file processing API only after receiving all files in bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Lambda which listens to s3 events.  We will receive three files in s3 bucket and lambda should trigger the file processing API call only after receiving three files in the bucket.

My approach:

Create a counter table in DynamoDB with Date,count as items

Every time we receive a s3 event,
Retrieve the count value from table and if value is less than 3
Add/Update entry for Date and increase the count value.

Once the count = 3 , trigger the file processing API.

Any help is appreciated.  Please correct if my approach have issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Should the Lambda function delete the 3 objects after they are processed? Should they be processed after every 3 uploads, or are the 3 files related to each other some way (eg same base name)? What happens if multiple files are uploaded at the same time (eg 12) -- how would the Lambda function know which ones to process?

Comment: We have three different files, file1, file2 and file3 all are related to each other.  They should be processed after all the three files are uploaded.  Lambda does check the file name, if the count is more than 3 we will not process it and generate error report.  @JohnRotenstein I can keep counter for each file so I can keep track of individual file.  Dynamo entries, Date -->file1counter,file2counter,file3counter.  Please help me if they are any better approaches.  Thank you!

Comment: How does it know which 3 files to process together -- is it based on the filenames? (Please provide an example.) Or does it simply need to run for every 3 files, regardless of their name? Can the objects be deleted after processing, or do they need to be kept? (Can they be moved after processing?) More information, please!

Comment: Contents: S3bucket 20220620 and files are Employee, EmployeeDetails,EmployeeExpense.

Lambda: Will get notification every time a S3 event occurs and it calls file processing API. 

File Processing API:  Before files are processed will check s3bucket contents if the bucket have all the three files it will process the files if not generate error report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation appears to be:

- Files are being created in an Amazon S3 bucket
- You have an AWS Lambda function that will process the files
- The Lambda function is configured to run when an object is created in the S3 bucket
- However, you only want to process the files after they have "all" been uploaded to S3

The Lambda function will be triggered after *every* object is created. You should add code to the start of the Lambda function that checks whether all of the desired objects are present (eg by listing the contents of the bucket and path). If so, it can process the objects and then delete them.

Comment: Thank you, instead of having counter checking for the contents of the s3 bucket is much better.